# How to enable caching in google chrome in cypress

Tags: automated-tests, cypress

I have an application that loads the main.js file. Running tests on Cypress every time a "cy.Visit" loads it, if using Google. Other browsers don't have this problem, they cache this file, how do I get cypress to cache it on google?

I can't find information about this problem anywhere. It confuses me that in other browsers everything works as it should.

I want to enable caching of this file when running a test. Otherwise, every "visit" it downloads it again.

i use cypress": "^10.3.0"

Comment: do you want to enable cache in chrome while running this test?

Comment: Yes, otherwise it slows down my tests every time

Comment: what version of cypress are you using?

Comment: cypress": "^10.3.0",

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found a solution to the problem

Google's security policy implies that if there is a problem with the certificate, caching is disabled. see chromium bugs https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=110649#c8 and https://github.com/cypress-io/cypress/issues/7307

The problem can be solved by adding the certificate to the trusted ones. Certificates can be found along the path cy/production/proxy/certs/

Comment: Where is this `cy` folder located that you refer to?

Answer (score -1):

You can do this by using the chrome command line switches listed [here](https://peter.sh/experiments/chromium-command-line-switches/#app-cache-force-enabled). The one you are looking for is `--app-cache-force-enabled`.

To use this in cypress, you have to configure it in your config file.

The examples of how to do that are available [here](https://docs.cypress.io/api/plugins/browser-launch-api#Modify-browser-launch-arguments). Your code should look something like below.

```js
    if (browser.family === 'chromium' && browser.name !== 'electron') {
      launchOptions.args.push('--app-cache-force-enabled');
    }
    return launchOptions
```

Comment: This is a good answer. But it didn't work for me, cypress selectively caches js files in my tests. In some, he shakes again, and sometimes everything is ok. Might be a problem with my app.