# How to simulate a browser's back action with HTTP POST reload in Cypress?

Tags: cypress

I'm using cypress. I want to automate a flow where an HTML page is loaded by an HTTP POST to display a bunch of links. Each of the links loads new pages. On clicking browser's back button, browser performs reload with a POST again (usually comes from a disk cache). Subsequently, I want to navigate to other links on the page and perform the same back.

I'm using `cy.go('back')` to simulate the back operation. However, the automation gets stuck after the `back` operation with the browser displaying:

```
This web page requires data that you entered earlier in order to be properly displayed. You can send this data again, but by doing so you will repeat any action this page previously performed.
```

I'm using Chrome 117 for the test.

Here is my code:

```
describe('test', () => {
  const visit = () => {
    cy.visit('https://example.org');
    // Click button performs a POST request and reloads the page
    cy.get('#button').click();
  };

  it('Iterate over all links and back', () => {
    visit();
    cy.get('a.link')
      .as('alias')
      .each((el, index) => {
        cy.get('@alias').eq(index).click();
        /* Do my thing */
        cy.go('back');
      });
  });
})
```

If I replace `cy.go('back')` with `visit()`, it works. However, it defeats the purpose of simulating browser's back navigation.

How do I make `cy.go('back')` work in this scenario?

EDIT: Re-POST in itself is not an issue for me as it works the same way while simulating this manually in a browser. The browser serves the request via disk cache. Cypress network logs show the failure reasons as `net::ERR_CACHE_MISS` in Chrome and `NS_ERROR_DOCUMENT_NOT_CACHED` in Firefox. I also added Cypress proxy to trust store as suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73034463/1112010) to enable disk caching but the issue persists.

Answer (score 3):

It's not a bug, it's normal for situations where the cache has expired - `ERR_CACHE_MISS`.

If you want to avoid the message, try adding configuration to the browser statup.

**cypress.config.js**

```js
module.exports = defineConfig({
  e2e: {
    setupNodeEvents(on, config) {
      on("before:browser:launch", (browser = {}, launchOptions) => {
        if (browser.family === 'chromium' && browser.name !== 'electron') {
          launchOptions.args.push('--disable-prompt-on-repost')
        }
      })
      return config
    })
  }
})
```

Comment: `ps -ef` tells me that the browser is already running with `--disable-prompt-on-repost`. That's default behavior.

Comment: If it's default, why have it - can you use it to turn it off? If it's already running, why are you seeing the message?

Answer (score 2):

I am not clear on what the test is testing, but if re-POST-ing is the issue, the second POST can be blocked.

Using the same `cy.intercept()` twice within the loop, the first one is allowed to proceed, and the second one is blocked.

This works because the last `intercept` set is the one that will be used.

Something like this:

```js
cy.get('a.link')
  .as('alias')
  .each((el, index) => {
    cy.intercept('POST-url-here', req => req.continue())  // this one goes through
    cy.get('@alias').eq(index).click()
    ...
    cy.intercept('POST-url-here', req => req.destroy())  // this one is blocked
    cy.go('back')

    cy.get('#button').should('be.visible')
  })
```

To make sure the loop is running at a sensible pace for the page refresh, add a line after the `cy.go('back')` that asserts something unique to the "back" page is visible.

Otherwise, the test might overrun itself.

Depending on what you need to assert WRT `go('back')`, you can change `req.destroy()` to stubbing, and `cy.wait('@post')`

```js
    ...
    cy.intercept('POST-url-here', {stub-data-here}).as('post')  // stub and alias
    cy.go('back')

    cy.wait('@post').then(interception => {
      // test interception request here
    })
  })
```

---

The use of `alias` to prevent "detached-from DOM" is a nice touch, you would also be able to avoid it by for-looping (so you don't depend on actual link elements, just the count.

```js
cy.get('a.link').then($links => {
   const count = $links.length
   for (let index = 0; index < count; index++) {
     cy.intercept('POST-url-here', req => req.continue())
     cy.get('a.link').eq(index).click()
     ...
     cy.intercept('POST-url-here', req => req.destroy())
     cy.go('back')
     cy.get('#button').should('be.visible')
   }
})
```

This works because the for-loop variables are in the test `<iframe>` and the refresh from `cy.go('back')` occurs in the app `<iframe>`

Comment: `cy.go('back')` is the one causing the re-POST. Re-POSTing is not an issue but somehow the browser/cypress doesn't allow the re-POST and instead displays the error message - 'This web page requires data that you entered earlier in order to be properly displayed. You can send this data again, but by doing so you will repeat any action this page previously performed.'

Comment: IIUC, you're proposing that I intercept re-POST. However, that's not my intention. I want the POST to go through just like it does when simulating this manually with a browser (disk cache). Cypress network logs show the failure reasons as `net::ERR_CACHE_MISS` in Chrome and `NS_ERROR_DOCUMENT_NOT_CACHED` in Firefox.

Comment: Indeed, but that's not the issue - I think the re-POST is blocked because of the error you first posted so `cy.intercept()` will never see the re-POST.